# How to avoid line break between date string ? [React Native]

Tags: react-native

I want to display a result without split my date string when it have to do line break.

```
<Text>
   '10 MAY 2019 - 15 MAY 2019'
</Text>
```

```
expected result : 

10 MAY 2019 -      

15 MAY 2019    



actual result :

10 MAY 2019 - 15   

MAY 2019
```

Comment: Can't you use `<br/>`?

Comment: If it is html, we usually use "<pre></pre>" tags to avoid formatting by the browser.

Answer (score -1):

To add line break you have to add '\n' like below:-

```
<Text>
   '10 MAY 2019 -' {'\n'} '15 MAY 2019'
</Text>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I think OP wants a way of having it done automatically